# Does Appfog support TurtoiseSVN?

Tags: git, svn, appfog

Does Appfog support TurtoiseSVN for version control? The official website only seem to provide details on Git.

Is there any tutorial or support that I can take? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, they don't support deployments from any versioning system, not Git either. They only support their own "af" command line tool for pushing code to the servers.

> "AppFog no longer uses Git to deploy apps. The af CLI tool replaces Git as the deployment mechanism."

See https://docs.appfog.com/getting-started/af-cli for information about their command line tool.

Comment: Yes it seems so isnt it.! Thank you Jesper for information. I have a google app engine project put on turtoisesvn and I want to deploy it somewhere else. Any suggestions you can give?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't think of anything except of manually cloning the repository and pushing it to the host via their normal deployment method.